# How to show the subpages from the Foundation top-bar like a mouse hover on a touch device

Tags: zurb-foundation

I'm using the top-bar from Foundation and this works great. Only when you have a touch device with a larger screen for example the iPad then it shows the desktop view op the top-bar. That is fine only when you klick a menu it opens directly that main page instead off showing a dropdown with the subpages like when you hover it with a mouse on the desktop.

Is there a way to show the subpages instead off oping the main page?

Answer (score 0):

Make the clickable instead of hover:

```
<nav class="top-bar" data-topbar role="navigation" data-options="is_hover: false">
```

Reference: http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/components/topbar.html

Comment: If I add this the menu is clickable in the normal browsers. I want it only clickable on a touch device and hover on a normal browser. I can not find this in the documentation.